# Facebook session sharing between my app and safari/Facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I have included Facebook login/registration in my iOS app using old Facebook SDK.
when user clicks on Facebook login button in app pop-up opens and asks for user credentials, but I want my app to auto login users if they are already logged in to their Facebook account on device using safari/Facebook app.

I am searching this from last 3 days but no success yet

Comment: Are you using iOS6 simulator?

Comment: managed to solve this by change in appdelegate.but still if facebook native app is installed and not logged in to that, my app redirects to native app but doesn't take use back to my app after login